# How should I write a function in Python that check whether a user has fetched some url or not?

Tags: python, url, fetch

I'm studying Python and I'd like to have some hints on how to write it as I read about the implementation of a fetch(url) function as follows:

```
_cache = {}
def fetch(url):
    user = os.environ['USER']
    if user not in _cache:
        _cache[user] = {}
    if url not in _cache[user]:
        _cache[user][url] = requests.get(url).content
    return _cache[user][url]
```

and I'm trying to figure out how to modify this kind of function  in order it checks wether a user has fetched some url or not, assuming that fetching a resource from web might take 0.1 seconds, while fetching it on the cache provides an instant result.

It should be something like

```
import sys # ignore
sys.path.insert(0,'.') # ignore
from Root.fetch import fetch


def did_fetch(user, url):
    pass #return if url has been fatched by user
```

with the function to be implemented inside

Comment: "and I'm trying to figure out how to modify this kind of function in order it checks wether a user has fetched some url or not" is that not what's going on here? `if url not in _cache[user]:`?

Comment: I read that the function I wrote in the question fetches a page from the web. To avoid re-fetching the same pages twice, which is pretty slow, it caches them per user (it figures out the current user by looking at os.environ['USER']); but I don't understand if the same function checks wether a user has fetched the url or not, and how to modify that function in order to perform this check.

Comment: It already does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to find all process running, and then loop through each process and see if say Facebook is in there, it won't show the URL of the page but it will show what you see on the tab, you can use that

```
import ctypes  # process find

EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int),
                                     ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible
####### Modules to gather data
titles = []  # Empty list for titles (As String Objects)


def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
    if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
        buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
        titles.append(buff.value)
    return True


EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)

if 'YOUR TITLE OF WEBPAGE NOT URL' in titles:
    print('DO SOMETHING HERE')


print(titles)
```

Edit: To answer your comment, I've adjusted it like this, not sure how you want the user bit to work, so I left that out, if you give further explanation then I might be able to figure something out, also, this only works if the tab is currently open, so yeah

```
import ctypes  # process find


def did_fetch(url):
    EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
    EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int),
                                         ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
    GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
    IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible
    ####### Modules to gather data
    titles = []  # Empty list for titles (As String Objects)

    def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
        if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
            buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
            GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
            titles.append(buff.value)
        return True

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)

    for process in titles:
        if url in process:
            return True


did_fetch('Facebook')
```

Comment: Thanx for your fast answer :) Could you suggest me something like the example that I just wrote down in the second part of my post? Ty :)

Comment: thank you! I tried to run the code and the compiler gave me the following error: ERROR: test_not_cached (Root.test.test.Test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/projects/m2omebf7t359udi55ph7cpbq33di10n2fm9oa8aor3w5kjjxtro1orw5se3ifg06bt9/Root/test/test.py", line 20, in test_not_cached
    assert did_fetch(_USER_1, _URL_1) is False
TypeError: did_fetch() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
FAILED (errors=1)        Can u help me fix it?

Comment: That's really weird because I didn't get that, mine works fine, did you just add the user bit in, cuz don't do that? Have you pip installed ctypes?

Comment: Sorry I'm still almost a newbie in Python :) What do you mean exactly? Because I think that the problem here is that the compiler tells: TypeError: did_fetch() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. You know a way how to fix it through your code?

Comment: what that is saying is that you put two items into the did_fetch argument, instead of just 'Facebook', is that what happened?

Comment: sorry i noticed i replied above :) look at the code I wrote down

Comment: where? I'm a bit confused now

Comment: I added an answer to my own question, there you can find the code that i wrote

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly, that's the code I wrote down, based on your advice:

```
import sys # ignore
sys.path.insert(0,'.') # ignore
from Root.fetch import fetch

import ctypes  # process find

def did_fetch(user, url):
    EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
    EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int),
                                         ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
    GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
    IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible
    ####### Modules to gather data
    titles = []  # Empty list for titles (As String Objects)

    def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
        if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
            buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
            GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
            titles.append(buff.value)
        return True

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)

    for process in titles:
        if url in process:
            return True

did_fetch(user, url)
```

I used the template that the teacher gave me, and I implemented it with your advice... what's wrong in it?

Comment: try using exactly the code I showed you first if that works, it means that the issue is with your adjustment, this way we can figure out what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys # ignore
import os
sys.path.insert(0,'.') # ignore
from Root.fetch import fetch
import time

def did_fetch(user, url):
    os.environ['USER'] = user
    start = time.time()
    fetch(url)
    end = time.time()
    timed = end - start
    if timed > 0.1:
        return False
    return True
```